# How to allow app to upload image in my website

Tags: javascript, android

I make my app for my website by android studio ( classic method) , 
in MainActivity.java :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.toptipstricks.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and this code (AndroidManifest.xml) :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

so , my website for classified and need to upload images , but this app not allow , how can I made it allow to upload images ?
note : I'm new in  android studio so new in stackoverflow.com . 
thanks

Comment: Please include your code in-line instead of a screenshot of it. Also you will need to be more specific about  "this app not allow". Explain better what is the expected behaviour and what is the current behaviour, and if there are any errors, and what they say. Read "How to ask" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){  

            // Update message
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try{    

                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                File imageStorageDir = new File(
                                       Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                       Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                       , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                // Create camera captured image file path and name 
                File file = new File(
                                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
                                + ".jpg");

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); 

                // Camera capture image intent
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                                              android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                // Create file chooser intent
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                // Set camera intent to file chooser 
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                                       , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

              }
             catch(Exception e){
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

        }




 @Override 
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                   Intent intent) { 

 if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
 {  

        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;

        }

       Uri result=null;

       try{
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                result = null;

            } else {

                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData(); 
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

 }

}
```

Comment: follow this tutorial http://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128